# Ogg metadata - Vorbis Comment end

Tags: metadata, ogg, vorbis

I want to implement a class to read vorbis comments. I know that a *field* will start with a *field name*, followed by an *equal sign* and the *value*. But how does it end? Documentation makes me think that a semicolon will end the field but I checked an ogg file with a hex editor and I cannot see any.

This is how I think it should look like in a file :

```
TITLE=MY SUPER TITLE;
```

The *field name* is **title**, followed by the *equals sign* and then the value is **MY SUPER TITLE**. And finally the *semicolon* to end the field.

But instead inside my file, the fields look like this :

```
TITLE=MY SUPER TITLE....
```

It's almost as above but there is no semicolon. The `.`'s are characters that cannot be displayed. I thought okay, it seems like the dots represent a value that will say "*this is the end of the field!!*" but they are almost always different. I noticed that there are always exactly 4 dots. The first dot has always a different value. The other free have usually a value of 0. But not always...

My question now, how does a *field* end? How do I read this comment?

Also, yeah I know that there are libraries and that I should use them instead of reinventing the wheel over and over again. I will use libraries later but first I want to know how to do it myself. Educational purpose only.

Answer (score 2):

Each field is preceded by a little-endian 32-bit integer that indicates the number of bytes to read.  You then convert the bytes to a string via UTF8.

See [NVorbis' implementation](https://nvorbis.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NVorbis/VorbisStreamDecoder.cs) (LoadComments(...)) for details.

Comment: Is there a reliable way to find the start of the comments field?  The documentation is a little vague on this point.